# How to get one DCOM Server per client

Tags: c#, .net, dcom

Due to the nature of the legacy code we need one DCOM server per client (lots of static and global data in the server code).

We have utilised the Enterprise Services .NET library to achieve a basic implementation.

Before we can fix it properly (which means months+ of work) we would like to have a usable system for 20 or so users which means one server per client.

Is this at all possible with .NET, C# and DCOM?

EDIT: (More Technical info)
The client is a thread\session in a IIS Hosted process. We have a web api that logs into our server gets some data and logs out.

Comment: What do you mean by "DCOM server per client" in this context? Your post is devoid of technical details. Usually with any client/server system a single server is shared by multiple clients, and DCOM supports this scenario without any issue.

Comment: I would like one server per client - not sure how to make it simpler than that. What technical detail is missing?

Comment: By far the simplest way is to *not* use the Enterprise Services library.  Just a simple DLL that runs as an in-process server.  So there automatically is only one instance of the server per client.

Comment: If you are voting down - can you provide a reason.

Comment: So, for *each* incoming web api call, you want to create a *new* process hosting your COM object, invoke a few methods on the object  from your web api method implementation and then just let the process exit after the web api method returns data to the caller? Is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelDomashchenko yes that's it.

Comment: Can you provide more info on the architecture please? So: Where is the server running? what is the client about? How is the server hosted? Do you a plan a solution so that each computer of each user gets a full solution including client and server executables? What is the target of transformation? What is the longterm target? More information on deployment is also of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COM+ Application Pooling for that. Inherit your service from `ServicedComponent` and set application activation to `ActivationOption.Server` using the `ApplicationActivation` attribute.

You'd need to install your assembly into GAC which means you need to sign it and you need to register it with regsvcs.exe

Then open Component Services snap-in in mmc.exe, find your newly registered application, open Properties, switch to Pooling & Recycling tab, set Pool Size to some reasonable value and set Activation Limit to 1. Also set Expiration Timeout for COM+ to shut down old processes.

After that COM+ would create a new process for every new instance of your COM object that you'll be creating.

Here's my sample code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.EnterpriseServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: ApplicationActivation(ActivationOption.Server)]
[assembly: ApplicationAccessControl(false)]

namespace SingleUseServer
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [Guid("6C3295E3-D9C9-40E3-AFBD-1398D4D1E344")]
    public interface IService
    {
        int GetProcessId();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("Test.Service")]
    [Guid("6B198197-3E88-4429-883D-A818E4E447D3")]
    public class Service : ServicedComponent, IService
    {
        public int GetProcessId()
        {
            return Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks as though Activation Limit was the key. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can host COM services inside .NET look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx